# Creating lists with variable names in python

Tags: python

I want to create a set of lists using python, where the list names would be like:
a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = []
.
.
.
a100 = []
And I would like to iteratively populate each list using python. Any idea on how to do that?

---

Actually I was trying to code something like below:

---

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = []
.
.
.
a100 = []

for line in inp1:
    arr = line.split()
    a1.append(arr[1])
    a2.append(arr[2])
    a3.append(arr[3])
    .
    .
    .
    a100.append(arr[100])
```

---

I wanted any idea on how can this be done with multiple lists? my file has 101 columns. I want to put every column in a list, then want to perform some analysis.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't ask this on StackOverflow? They have millions of Python programmers and we have only thousands. I'm guessing that you'd get the answer faster there, as long as you make it clear that you've tried something on your own before asking others.

Comment: @NikeDattani really good question

Answer (score 5):

Use dictionaries

```py
rows = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
dict_rows = {}

for idx, i in enumerate(rows):
   dict_rows[f'a{idx}'] = i
```

The output of this little script is:
`{'a0': [1, 2, 3], 'a1': [1, 2, 3], 'a2': [1, 2, 3]}`

Dictionaries are iterable via keys.

Note: maybe next time try to give some more info on the script. Otherwise, it's a bit difficult to understand the question. I've supposed you have a list of lists and you want to "give them a name". If not, let me know

**Edit**
To create a dataframe from a table instead you can do

```py
import pandas as pd

rows = [...] # or you can obtain from a sting with file.striplines()
d = {}
for line in rows:
    for idx, data in enumerate(line.split()):
        if f'a{idx}' not in d: 
            d[f'a{idx}'] = []
        d[f'a{idx}'].append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: If the columns in the file are separated by a fixed separator (like a tab or a space), then simply calling `df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep="\t", header=None)` will work. If the columns are fixed width, then `df = pd.read_fwf()` can be used.

Comment: You can also use lists of lists or `numpy` arrays (2D, 3D, etc.) if you don't want to create a dataframe.

Comment: @SRMaiti yes, but it dipends on the file that have to be parsed.

Comment: You can create a named tuple out of np arraies? Maybe i've lost something @GeoffHutchison

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini - no, but you can use lists of lists or 2D numpy arrays to store the data from OP. The question is, in some sense, asking for storing lists of lists => a 2D array. Depending on the analysis requested, it's possibly faster to do on a 2D `ndarray`.